# makefile --print-data-base not listing all variables

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following line

`SRC_QSTR += $(SRC_C) $(STM_SRC_C) $(LIB_SRC_C)`

In the `--print-data-base` section, it expands it as

```
# makefile (from 'Makefile', line 211)
SRC_QSTR = $(SRC_MOD) $(addprefix py/,$(filter-out $(SRC_QSTR_IGNORE),$(PY_O_BASENAME:.o=.c)) emitnative.c) $(SRC_C) $(STM_SRC_C) $(LIB_SRC_C)
```

I would like to know what `$(SRC_MOD)` is equal to but it's not present at all in the `--print-data-base` portion.

Is it possible to force it to be expanded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to force it to be expanded?

It possible to print its value. Add the following line at the end of the makefile:

```
$(info SRC_MOD=${SRC_MOD})
```

It is also possible that `SRC_MOD` is not set, so that its expansion is an empty string.